# Cocoa: setting the key equivalent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key, menuitem, hotkeys

i want to set the key equivalent of a menuitem with [menuitem setKeyEquivalent:(NSString *)s],
 how can i do that if i have multiple modifiers ?

i tried:

```
unichar shift = NSShiftKeyMask, cmd = NSCommandKeyMask;
NSMutableString *keyequiv = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[keyequiv appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacter:&shift, 1]];
[keyequiv appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacter:&cmd, 1]];
[keyequiv appendString:@"x"];
[menuItem setKeyEquivalent:keyequivalent];
```

but that doesnt work.

Comment: Any way to setup F1 as the key equivalent? thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The modifier key masks are just that: masks, not characters. You can't insert them into the key equivalent string. To apply them, use [`setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000265-BAJHAEEH)

```
[menuItem setKeyEquivalentModifierMask: NSShiftKeyMask | NSCommandKeyMask];
[menuItem setKeyEquivalent:@"x"];
```

As with any other mask, use the bitwise OR operator `|` to form combinations. See ["Setting a Menu Item's Key Equivalent"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/SettingMenuKeyEquiv.html) for more details.

Comment: Note that NSShiftKeyMask, NSCommandKeyMask etc are deprecated. Instead use NSEventModifierFlagShift, NSEventModifierFlagCommand , etc.

Answer (score 15):

The `setKeyEquivalent:` method is used to specify the character which triggers the command, but not the modifiers. It will set default modifiers by examining the character you pass. If you pass a lowercase character, it will use just <kbd>command</kbd>. If you pass an uppercase character, it will use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>. Because of this, you simply need to do this for <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>:

```
[menuItem setKeyEquivalent:@"X"];
```

If you want to use other modifiers, you then call `setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:` with the proper constants, chosen from `NSShiftKeyMask`, `NSAlternateKeyMask` (option), `NSCommandKeyMask`, and `NSControlKeyMask`.

Answer (score 4):

Example for Swift 2.0:

```swift
let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSBackspaceCharacter)], count: 1) as String
item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = Int(NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue | NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue)
item.keyEquivalent = key
```

Answer (score 2):

Example for Swift 3.0:

```
item.keyEquivalent = "x"
item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = [NSAlternateKeyMask, NSCommandKeyMask]
```

Answer (score 2):

Example for Swift 5:

```
item.keyEquivalent = "q"
item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = [.command]
```

Comment: `item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .option.union(.command)`